# Getting post web service response as undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

```
 app.controller("blankCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$parse',
    function($scope, $http, $parse) {
        $scope.login = function() {
            $scope.spice = 'tooo';
            alert("hiii");
            $.ajax({                                                  
                url : "http://edudux.com/manage/index.php?/api/login",
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert("mobile:"+data.mobile+"\npassword:"+data.password);
                }
            });
        }
    }]);
```

I am getting post web service response as undefined after executing above code.I am using angularjs to build cross platform project.

Comment: you should use $http and not $.ajax

Comment: print `data` in console and then check the issue

Comment: You are in Angularjs so you can either choose `$http` or `$resource`. `$.ajax` is for jQuery.

Comment: after using $http I am not getting any response @harishr

Comment: Can you show the code how you tried `$http`?

Comment: $http({                                                  
           url : "http://edudux.com/manage/index.php?/api/login",
           dataType:"json",
           type:"POST",
           //json:"Success",
           success:function(data)
           {    
            alert(data);
               alert("mobile:"+data.mobile+"\npassword:"+data.password);
               
           }
       });

Comment: @kalpita check the answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

Although as suggested in the comments that angular does have a `$http` module which can be used for the async requests. Yet if i see your code as you mentioned `POST` request which it does not seem to be because you are missing the `type:"POST"`.

You can use it in angular way with `$http`:

```
$http({                                                  
    url : "http://edudux.com/manage/index.php?/api/login",
    method: 'POST'
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: console.log(response.data); showing [object Object]

Comment: tahts fine you are getting the object in response

Comment: I want success as a resonse

Comment: That is your API which is sending some objects instead of "success"

Comment: api response is { "Success": [ "mobile": "9860292514", "password": "123456", } ] } but I am getting as [object Object]

Comment: how to de-serialize that object